# Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I was wondering if somebody help me with next error.

I have an app -windows service, which by a timer calls some function for manipulating with database (linq2sql).

Approximately after 3-5 calls I always receive next error "Thread was being aborted." in next source code

```
 var ctx= new myLinq2SqlDataContext();
 var res = ctx.SomeData.Where();
```

I don't use multithreading! I use lock statement when call a function for working with database. I have only 1 service which works with context.

Here is my code snippet

```
public partial class DataService : ServiceBase
    {
         private static object timerProcessLockObject = new object();
         static object _receiverTimerLockObject = new object();

         void OnStart()
         {
            if (_receiverTimer == null)
            {
                lock (_receiverTimerLockObject)
                {
                    if (_receiverTimer == null)
                    {                      
                        _receiverTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(ReceiverTimer_TimerCallback), null, 0, 60000);    
                     }
                 }

            }
         }

         private void ReceiverTimer_TimerCallback(object state)
         {       
            lock (timerProcessLockObject)
            {   
                  var receiveService = new ReceiverService();
                  receiveService.GetData();
             }
          }    
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class ReceiverService : IReceiverService
    {      
        public void GetData()
        {          
            IDataControler myController = new DataControler();
            myController.GetData();           
        }           
    }

    public class DataControler : IDataControler
    {      
        public void GetData()
        {                
            IMyDomainService myDomainService = new MyDomainService();
            myDomainService.SomeFunc();          

            IMyExtraDomainService myExtraService = new MyExtraDomainService();
            var data = myExtraService.SomeFuns();

            var convertedData = ConvertData(data);
            myDomainService.SaveData(convertedData);

            DBConnection newConnection = new DBConnection();
            myDomainService.AddNewConnection(newConnection);           
        }    
     }

    public class MyExtraDomainService : IMyExtraDomainService
    {   
        public IList<Entity> SomeFuns()
        {
            try
            {             
                var myCtx = new MyLinq2SqlDataContext();         //!!!! Here I receive error
                return myCtx.SomeEntities.Where(...).ToList();
            }   
            catch (Exception exc)
            {              
                throw;
            }            
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Here is stack trace

```
at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
   at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)                                                                                       at MY FUNCTION call
```

What is the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using transactions? DTSC commits on the background thread. I am guessing you have not included all the code, as I see no loop?

Comment: hmmm... now it sounds more like a WCF issue. Try searching for "WCF Thread was being aborted". I remember getting this error, but there are many causes. Such as a WCF timeout, caused by a slow database call (deadlock?). Does it take awhile to throw the error?

Comment: Also I would update the question to mention that the timeout is within a WCF service. As that is quite important. At least it looks like it is ... is it?

Comment: I deleted the reference to WCF service  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] and reference from web.config
 but I still receive the same error

Comment: That was my bad, maybe try a `using (var myCtx = new...` .. but I'm running out of ideas :p

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace of exception? Also you are using multithreading as you use Timer class: the callback is executed in separate thread.

Comment: I've added exception stack trace above

Comment: @user970742 try also setting `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single` in the `ServiceBehavior` attribute.

Comment: I had done this without success [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

Comment: See this question/answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/9380/7527
This was the issue in my case